# Dynamically load meta tag information based on page name?

Tags: php, html, meta

I have a website that uses php to load header and footer files. I am trying to add meta tags, and need to have them loaded dynamically based on the page name. The page name is indicated on each page before the header is pulled in, for example:

```
<?php $page="Home" ?>
<?php include("../../includes/header.php"); ?>
```

The header file is laid out like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title> Company Name | <?php print $page;?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/styles.css" />
```

...and so on (body starts in the header file so that the nav bar can be loaded)

I am confused as to how I will dynamically load meta tag information such as keywords and descriptions since the page name is declared in the actual page file. Should I use a series of if/or statements to load the mega tags? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Do the same thing for these variables as you did for `$page`

Comment: Oh... better use normal CMS or framework instead this horror.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your php file like:

```
<?php
$page = 'home';
$meta_description = 'description for home…';
include('../../includes/header.php');
include('../../includes/view/'.$page.'.php');
include('../../includes/footer.php');
?>
```

And you can use it for all your pages.